Apex deployment with full coverage fails without any errors
I'm trying to deploy a salesforce "package", aka a zip file, using metadata API on production environments
On my developer edition account this deployment is successful
The test coverage for this new code is 100%, the associated user also AuthorApex permission
However the deployment fails on production environments, the response also shows no errors
During deployment I'm running with testlevel = RunSpecifiedTests to include only tests which are introduced part of this deployment
The tests cover 100% of new code being deployed
This is the response from checkDeployStatus SOAP Action
{'state': 'Failed',
 'state_detail': None,
 'deployment_detail': {'total_count': '13',
  'failed_count': '0',
  'deployed_count': '13',
  'errors': []},
 'unit_test_detail': {'total_count': '2',
  'failed_count': '0',
  'completed_count': '2',
  'errors': []}}

What am I missing?

What's the code coverage look like for the entire deployment (not just the new code)? Your new code may have 100% coverage, but if the other classes in the deployment have 0 coverage (or if the coverage for any class is below 75%) then the deployment will fail.

@DerekF the documentation states I can use runspecifiedtests as long as the code coverage is 75% of classes and triggers each
Additionally, would a lack of code coverage not show up in the multiple error fields?

How do you deploy? A command? Can you share it?

Is there an api version mismatch?

@stackasaur, nope, I'm using Winter'25, throughout, additionally the same zipfile deployment works with developer edition

@AndriiMuzychuk, I'm deploying with metadata SOAP API call, exactly the same way it's recommended in the documentation

@ApexSam we once had a strange cache issue with coverage when deploying to other orgs and this was fixed by replacing IsTest with lowercase isTest in test class definition and all test methods. try and see if this help fix the issue

Have you tried this on diverse prod orgs, i.e. it clearly doesn't fail due to org limits (e.g. 6 MB Apex)? Can you checkOnly deploy, then deployValidated? At which point does it fail then? Does the deployment contain field conversions, e.g. Lookup to Master-Detail? Could you state the exact call, e.g. do you use ignoreWarnings=false, rollbackOnError etc.? Have you produced a debug log and scrutinized it?

Hello @ApexSam - what does  Salesforce Setup -> Deployment Status page for that failed deployment say?
